# Is there a better way to get the days since 1.1.1970

Tags: php, time, timezone

I need a function which returns the number of days since 1.1.1970 but depending on the timezone.
I wrote the following function but was wondering if there is a better way to do it (some better way to determinate the offset from gmt would be a good thing).

```
function getDaysSinceUnix($time = null){
    if($time === null){$time = time();}
    $day = 24*60*60;
    $offset = intval(substr(date('O'),0,-2))*60*60;
    return intval(floor(($time+$offset)/$day));
}
```

If not, is there something you would add that could give this function more stability ?

Comment: Actually, I'm gonna borrow your function to replace mine.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Ahahaha oh well I am very pleased that I was able to help you, I never though that someone would use my code :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
function getDaysSinceUnix( $time = 0, $timeZone = Null )
{
    $time = "@$time";
    $tz = new DateTimeZone( $timeZone ?: date_default_timezone_get() );
    return date_create( $time )->setTimeZone( $tz )->diff( date_create( '1970-01-01', $tz ) )->days;
}
```

If no Time Zone is passed, current Time Zone is used.

Comment: There might be a problem, if I use the parameter `time()+60*60*2` for your function it returns `16925` but in my timezone it is 22:13 so it should return `16926` so it is a hour off because  `time()+60*60*3` results in `16926`. Do you know why this is the case ?

Comment: What is your TimeZone?

Comment: Yes, my function has a different result than your. Do you want compare actual timezone time with 1-1-1970 UTC or with 1-1-1970 CET (Berlin)?

Comment: I don't want to compare those, but I need the correct amount of days depending on the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

The [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) library is pretty much the gold standard for PHP date/time work.

```
Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp(0)->diffInDays();
```

Comment: Ok that seems nice but I really don't want to use a library just for this one porpose, but thank you any way for your alternative.

Comment: @Feirell Libraries tend to handle all the weird edge cases, have minimal performance impact, are incredibly easy to install and manage via Composer, and as you can see result in cleaner, more readily understandable code. Up to you, ultimately.

Comment: Mhh yeah you are right, this would be a benefit. But with a library I will not learn anything (and this is a private project) so a self made is the idea :)